# Wso2 5.8 with 3 authentication steps

Tags: java, wso2, two-factor-authentication, password-policy, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to configure wso2 with 3 authentication steps.

1. Basic authentication
2. SMSOTP
3. Password policy authenticator (which will display the password change screen 
   after a predefined time)

However it seems that all these 3 combined are not working, if I use the basic with one of the 2 or 3 rd is working fine, but all three combined are not working. I dont get any error, just that the 3rd step is always skipped. Any ideas?

Comment: This issue is fixed with the new connector version (1.0.16) and is available at the connector store https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/isconnector/details/502efeb1-cc59-4b62-a197-8c612797933c

Answer (score 0):

There is a limitation in the 'password policy authenticator' which will work only if the pervious authenticator is the basic authentication. I have created a git [issue](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/7021) to track it.

As a workaround, you can have the steps in this order.

step 1 - Basic authenticator

step 2 - Password policy authenticator

step 3 - SMSOTP

---

[Update]

This issue is fixed with the new connector version (1.0.16) and is available at the [connector store](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/isconnector/details/502efeb1-cc59-4b62-a197-8c612797933c)